Create list of dates in Google Sheets based on day-of-month schedule
Given a StartDate, an EndDate, and a schedule like this in Google Sheets:



Day of Month
Amt
Info




1
$800.00
Rent


1
$155.00
Electric


10
$58.00
Credit Card


16
$87.00
Student Loans


23
$19.99
Netflix


31
$78.00
Water



Create a list of dates between StartDate/EndDate that generates real dates for each day of month in the schedule.
For example, StartDate = 11/01/2024 and EndDate = 12/31/2024 produces:



Date
Amt
Info




11/1/2024
$800.00
Rent


11/1/2024
$155.00
Electric


11/10/2024
$58.00
Credit Card


11/16/2024
$87.00
Student Loans


11/23/2024
$19.99
Netflix


11/30/2024
$78.00
Water


12/1/2024
$800.00
Rent


12/1/2024
$155.00
Electric


12/10/2024
$58.00
Credit Card


12/16/2024
$87.00
Student Loans


12/23/2024
$19.99
Netflix


12/31/2024
$78.00
Water



Bonus (not required but would be nice)
If the day of the month in the schedule is greater than the number of days in the current month, then map the scheduled day to the last day of the current month.
Generating Dates
I can use the Sequence function to generate dates between StartDate/EndDate:
=SEQUENCE(EndDate-StartDate+1,1,StartDate)
The problem is that this generates all dates in between and I see no way to reference the schedule.
How can this be accomplished?

Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as a plain text table to the question. Click here to create a markdown table, which is easier to copy/paste as well. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Updated with actual text. Great resource, thanks


Here's one approach you may test out:
=arrayformula(let(Σ,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),
 Δ,reduce(tocol(,1),unique(eomonth(sequence(F1-E1+1,1,E1),)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(let(Λ,date(year(c),month(c),Σ),if(Λ>c,c,Λ)),offset(Σ,,1,,2))))),
 filter(Δ,isbetween(choosecols(Δ,1),E1,F1))))



Exactly what I asked for, thank you. Very impressive. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time reading and altering it. I was hoping to add in pay days every 2 weeks starting on a given day for a given amount, but I'm not sure how to fit that into your formula. Would you take a look at that if I made another question for it?
